# How can i handle run time error in this code?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, runtime-error

Run time error occur when I run this code. why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *p, int);

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int n, k, ni = 0;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
         scanf("%d", p + j);
    
    sort(p, n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  //line 16
        if (*(p + i) != 0 && *(p + i) >= *(p + k - 1))  //line 17
            ni++;
    
    printf("%d", ni);
    
    return 0;
}

void sort(int *p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int *max = p + i;
        
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
            if (*(p + j) > *max)
                max = p + j;
        
        int c = *(p + i);
        *(p + i) = *max ;
        *max = c;
    }
}
```

and the error while not occur when I delete line 16 & 17 . but I don't know why ?

I want to handle the runtime error.

Comment: `int *p ;` What does `p` point to? Turn your warnings up, pay attention to them, and if you can use AddressSanitizer. https://godbolt.org/z/jzvE3P7Kn

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am not agree with you because when i delete line 16 & 17 the error will not occur

Comment: Welcome to *undefined behavior* where unrelated code changes will hide your errors

Comment: You can handle the run time error by making `p` point to a suitably aligned and sized block of memory, e.g. `p = calloc(n, sizeof(*p));`.

Comment: @amirheadayati you still haven't answered the question: _Where does `p` point to?_. Read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C learning material.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- `int *p;` defines an uninitialized pointer, to which you try and store data read by `scanf()`.  This has undefined behavior.

  You should instead define an array of length `n` after reading the value of `n` from the user.
- check the return value of `scanf()` to detect and reject invalid or missing input.
- use the array syntax `p[i]` instead of `*(p + i)`: both are equivalent  but `p[i]` is more readable.
- it is unclear what is the purpose of `k` and you do should test if `k - 1` is in the range of valid indices.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int *p, int);

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int n, k, ni = 0;
    
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) != 2 || n <= 0 || k < 1 || k > n)
        return 1;
    
    int p[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &p[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    sort(p, n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (p[i] != 0 && p[i] >= p[k - 1])  //line 17
            ni++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", ni);
    
    return 0;
}

void sort(int *p, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int *max = &p[i];
        
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (p[j] > *max)
                max = &p[j];
        }
        int c = p[i];
        p[i] = *max;
        *max = c;
    }
}
```